# set robot_description in program?

Tags: ros, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I read in command argument and set robot_description in c++ program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220254/set-robot_description-in-program?/) by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. It's just 'another parameter'.

Note: you will have to make sure that any other nodes that require that parameter will be started *after* your 'c++ program', or they'll most likely fail (most nodes (such as the `robot_state_publisher`) try to access parameters only once, at init). This can be tricky, as there is no guaranteed order in which nodes are launched.

Letting `roslaunch` set `robot_description` as a parameter takes care of this automatically, as "parameters will be stored on the Parameter Server before any nodes are launched" (from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#Setting_parameters)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DamnItROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/24967/damnitros/) on 2015-11-02**:
I agree with you. But the problem is that roslaunch is not friendly to IDE.
My plan is that I can setup a standalone c++ program for debug in IDE such as qtcreator/eclipse.
For the end user, I have other executable integrated into roslaunch.